# How can I extract vector from melted data

Tags: r, casting, melt

raw Data looks like this:

```
  type value
1  a    10
2  a    20
3  a    30
4  b    50
5  b    10
6  b    20
```

melted data looks like this:

```
1 a value 10
2 b value 10
```

I want to apply wilcox.test to a,b  To check whether a is greater than b.
How to do that?   thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to melt the data.

given a data.frame `raw` containing your `raw` (unmelted) data

```
wilcox.test(value ~ type, data = raw)
```

should work.

Comment: I did that: > wilcox.test(value ~ type, data=raw)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  value by type
W = XXXXXX, p-value < 3.3e-20
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0, but how can I know it is test a>b or b>a ?

Comment: I believe you are a R professional, can you suggest me some books to manipulate R data structure?

Comment: @user1138113 -- the test (by default) is two sided.

Comment: I want to test whether a is greater than b: I used "r=wilcox.test(value ~ type, data=df,paired=F,alternative='greater',conf.int = TRUE)", Is this test "first appeared in data ('a' in above example) greater than second" ?  Thank you very much for your help :-)

Comment: x will be the first by the ordering of the levels within `df$type`. Look at  `levels(df$type)`